# Run a system app in the Android emulator without gettting INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-keystore

I've successfully created a keystore to sign system apps to be tested on android emulators. I can install the apk on a 6.0 image but got no luck on a 8.0 image. It fails with the message:

> INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE Package xxx.yyy.zzz has no signatures that match those in shared user android.uid.system".

The keys that i used were the ones available on [aosp-mirror github](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_build/tree/master/target/product/security). Is there a way to sign an apk as a system app to be used on a 8.0 android emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use an Emulator without Google API's or Google Play Services.

Comment: I've downloaded an image without Google API's and it worked. Maybe those images come with a different platform key. Thanks @nicruo